# GraphicMagick PDF to jpeg black image in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick, gm

I'm trying to convert PDF images to jpeg thumbnails. Following is a sample code with GraphicMagick.

```
const gm = require("gm");
const imageMagick = gm.subClass({ imageMagick: true });

image = imageMagick(fileBuffer).selectFrame(0);

image.size(function onSizeComplete(err, size) {

   image.quality(40).resize('', 200)
     .toBuffer("jpeg", async function (error, buffer) {
        if (error) {
            logger.info("error buffer: " + error);
        } else {
            //upload the image
        }
      });
            
});
```

This code is working fine for PDF with more than 1 page. When I'm trying to convert PDF with a single page the thumbnail image is just black. I'm not able to figure out the issue.

Edit: I tried changing some code. If I remove the .resize() call it's working fine

Comment: it's black when running locally. not yet deployed it to lambda

Comment: Sorry - is it black only when uploaded to S3 or also black when generating a file locally?

Comment: I have not stored the file locally. Uploading it to S3 with the buffer generated on resizing. Will try it and see

Comment: Try locally to cross out your image generation code being incorrect

Comment: It is black in local as well.

Comment: I will remove the S3 tag then as this is limited to your JS code only :) I would advise to also change the code to not reference S3 and find a relative GraphicMagick tag if it exists